# How can I transfer file from host os to os running in virtual machine without using any removable disk?

Tags: windows, linux, vmware

I am trying to transfer a pdf file from my host OS(Windows 7) to  OS running on virtual machine(Linux-Backtrack) without using any removable device.Normal copy- paste is not working .How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need shared folders. Read this: http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Folder has been shared ! but where to open the shared folder in virtual machine?

Comment: Link only answers are generally discouraged in SO, please add the most relevant content in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

If no suggestions works, put your files in a FAT32 formatted pendrive. 
You'll see Mass Storage Device icon in bottom right corner of you VM window.
Right click press Connect(Disconnect from Host).

Works!